# $3D$ coordinates translation

Tags: 3d, transformation

I have CNC router carrying reflector with it's $X,Y,Z$ coordinates in $mm$
and laser tracker measuring position of reflector with spherical coordinates.
I was able to "crack" the math and convert spherical to Cartesian coordinates.

Now I need to translate Laser coordinates to CNC coordinates.
The idea is to measure $3$ points on CNC table $(0,0,0)$, $(X_{max}, 0, 0)$ and $(0,Y_{max},0)$ and construct a matrix, that will translate all the other measurements made by laser (to see how exact machine is).

**Both coordinate systems are isotropic** (same scale in mm) even though is assumed laser measurement is perfect and there may be (ARE) precision errors on CNC machine (due to technology/materials used, gravity, length of axis, construction errors)

**CNC axis and laser axis are parallel to each other**, but only if laser stands in front of the machine. Ideally we want 3 points based transformation to work even when from practical reasons laser has to be to the left or right of machine (X and Y are then swapped). Axis are aligned, but from my experiments it seems there isaround 0,111deg rotation in Yaxis and -0.0117deg in X axis. This may be due imperfect alignment of laser and machine, or maybe machine error.

I found 2D translation (ignoring Z coordinates, just offsetting them by Z0_laser) which works quite fine, but is not as accurate (up to 1mm difference when compared to Laser manufacturer provided tool using 3 points)

code I found is here:
https://gist.github.com/Clanrat/45cbcde78cb04fa12f9fb9caa03997cf

would it be possible to extend it for 3rd dimension, and do I need to start from scratch ?
I have a feeling I just need to replace 0 and 1 in matrix with coordinates from 3rd point as well as all the Z dimensions, but I have no clue how to do it.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are the CNC axis and your own axis parallel to each other ? Are both coordinate systems isotropic (i.e. same units/scale on the three axis) ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust they are isotropic (both in mm) and parallel. I updated my Q with more details.

Comment: But then you don't need three calibration points. One is enough, and it is pure translation, not requiring any matrix.

Comment: @YvesDaoust well Machine is not (as) perfect as Laser.
See the point pairs:
[link]http://gastan.sk/3Points.png

those 3 points are all on XY plane, but it seems there is a slight rotation in X and Y axis. Z I cannot figure.

Laser manufacturer can calibrate with just 3 points.
Shall you 3 point formula work nevertheless?

Can you maybe suggest more general model? possibly including all errors a physical machine can have? (Assuming Laser coordinates are perfect in all the ways)

Comment: Care to read my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have the 3D coordinates of the points corresponding to $(0,0,0),(X,0,0)$ and $(0,Y,0)$, let $P,Px,Py$.

If your system is correctly calibrated, the vectors $PPx$ and $PPy$ should be perfectly orthogonal, and have the same lengths. If not, you should either recalibrate, or adopt a more general transformation model. You will have to use at least 4 calibration points.

Otherwise, compute

$$PP_z=PP_x\times PP_y,$$

and the transformation will consist of the translation vector $P$ and the orthogonal transformation matrix with column vectors $\dfrac{PP_x}{X},\dfrac{PP_y}{Y}$ and $\dfrac{PP_z}{XY}$.